# how should I write my first email to co-supervisor?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, professorship, email, projects

My supervisor introduced me to a professor who has (already) accepted to be my co-supervisor, and wanted me to contact him and make an appointment. I want to write an email, but I do not know exactly what to write. My supervisor raved about his knowledge.

How can I explain my purpose of contacting?

Is the following a good email?

> Dear xx
>
> My name is ++++ , and I am a master student and my supervisor is
> Dr.+++++.
>
> First of all, I would like to thank you for agreeing to be my
> co-supervisor.
>
> I have read and heard a lot about your achievements and your extensive
> research experience in the field of artificial intelligence systems.
> so, I would like to discuss with you on topics such as AI, Machine
> learning which will help me get started in the right direction.
>
> Would it be possible to meet with you to further discuss?
>
> I am available Days and Times.
>
> Kind  Regards,
>
> ++++++
>
> XX

Comment: Perhaps thank him for agreeing to be your cosupervisor?

Comment: could you explain more? what other things should I include?

Comment: We don't know what you should write either. We need more context -- what is the purpose of this email? Have you met the person before?

Comment: @Austin Henley no, I have not met him before. and I am going to make an appointment. and meet him for the first time.

Comment: Well then you should also ask about meeting!

Comment: @Dawn  what do you mean? I did not get you.

Comment: The content of the email depends on what you want. You haven't specified what you want in your question, so we can't tell you what to write. I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Do not overthink it: http://phdcomics.com/comics.php?f=1047

Comment: XX means kiss kiss, no? I'd drop that. Keep in mind that your co-suepervisor, though respected and awesome, is a person, and is not likely to go berserk because a student made a little error in an email. Also, wouldn't it be interesting if that co-supervisor is active in this forum?

Comment: This question was closed as unclear, so the asker edited it... by removing all but one word? I am very confused.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas only. I don't think you need to praise him in an initial note. Just mention the general area in AI that you want to explore.

But the meeting should be at his convenience. Rather than tell him when you are available, let him set the meeting. If necessary you can indicate when you cannot meet if that is relevant.

You can thank him and tell him you are looking forward to working with him when you actually meet.

Comment: what do you mean? in this part "Just mention the general area in AI that you want to explore."

Comment: @nikki2 Buffy gave you a good outline - so just give a simple explanation of the focus of your research.